# Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances now offer instance size flexibility, helping you reduce your EC2 bill

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS just published information that [Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances now offer instance size flexibility, helping you reduce your EC2 bill](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/03/amazon-ec2-reserved-instances-now-offer-instance-size-flexibility-helping-you-reduce-your-ec2-bill/).

Does this apply to existing reserved instances or is it applicable only on new reserved instances which we purchase now onwards? Or we can avail this benefit on same instance family type?

Example : Suppose I purchased `r3.2xlarge` reserved instance. If I modified or change instance size from `r3.2xlarge` to `c3.xlarge` instance then the discounted rate of this RI can automatically apply for instance `c3.xlarge`?

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, help support the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96256/practical-cloud-computing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The announcement that you linked concerns the ability to take advantage of purchased Reserved Instances for different instance types **within the same instance family**.

For example, if you have purchased a `r3.2xlarge` Reserved Instance, then it will now apply for any instance in the `r3` family, including a `r3.4xlarge` (for which it would cover half the price).

It does *not* cover an instance in another family, such as `c3.xlarge`.

Also, please note that it only applies to **Regional Reserved Instances**, meaning RIs that do *not* have an Availability Zone assigned (which provides a capacity reservation, but only of the nominated instance type).

There is, however, the ability to purchase **Convertible Reserved Instances** that can be 'cashed-in', with the remaining value applied against a new Convertible Reserved Instance, even in a different family.

For more information, see the AWS Blog: [New – Instance Size Flexibility for EC2 Reserved Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-size-flexibility-for-ec2-reserved-instances/)

Comment: Both good and bad when come to internal billing for a corporate.  E.g. Dept X just reserved 2 x  c3 .*  intance,will only start it 1 month later. Dept Y happens need one c3.* before this happens. So Dept Y will automatically take up the c3.* reserved instance, end of the month, Dept Y is surprise it is free. But next month,  Dept X start the using the instance and notice.. hey, why I am being bill as on-demand.

Comment: @mootmoot Not quite. If a Reserved Instance isn't being utilized in an AWS Account during any particular hour, the pricing benefit will be made available to a linked account under consolidated billing. However, if the account that owns the Reserved Instance then uses the RI in the next hour (by launching a matching instance), then that owning account receives the RI benefit. In your example, if Dept X bought the RI but doesn't use it one hour, the benefit goes to Dept Y. If Dept X started an instance the next hour, it would receive the RI benefit, not Dept Y.

Comment: Hey John Rotenstein Thanks for answer..

I have query :  Suppose i have existing reserved instance R3.2xlarge which is purchased in Oct2016 if i terminate this instance and create new two instance R3.xlarge . In this case  (it would cover the price of reserved instance R3.2xlarge) can i avail this policy benefit.

Comment: Yes, that would now work. Please note that the Reserved Instance pricing benefit is not associated with a *specific* EC2 instance. Rather, the billing system looks for a matching instance each hour and applies the pricing benefit. So, if you have another `r3.2xlarge` that is running, it might take the RI discount before your 2 x `r3.xlarge`. Same billing benefit, but there is no definitive way to nominate which instance receives the benefit.

Comment: Hi @ShashiB if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.